# parsing and storing expression involving array

Tags: arrays, parsing, z3, equivalent

I have two integer arithmetic expressions involving array in a file. What is the best way to store each expression into memory.  so that equivalent formula becomes syntactically equivalent. comparing there structure we can find the equivalence. 
To check the equivalence first compare there structure if same then they are equivalent otherwise use the SMT solver.

Ex. a[i+2]+5 and a[i+3-1]+4+1 are equivalent.

At present I am representing a[i] = b[i] + z is  as wr(a, i, rd(b, i) + z). Where Write(wr) and Read (rd) are functions.

Comment: I haven't read the article because it's too expensive.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to understand what you are asking. But the theory of arrays already support read/write operations. The equality you put down as example can be coded like this:

```
(set-logic AUFLIA)

(declare-const i Int)
(declare-const a (Array Int Int))

(define-fun eq () Bool (= (+ (select a (+ i 2))       5)
                          (+ (select a (+ i (- 3 1))) (+ 4 1))))

; To prove equivalence, assert the negation and make sure the result is unsat:
(assert (not eq))

(check-sat)
```

This will result in `unsat` which proves that equality is true for all arrays `a`. (Note that we're asserting the negation of the equality.)

Is this what you are after?

Comment: Can we store these equation in memory in such a way that equivalent formula becomes syntactically equivalent. comparing there structure we can find the equivalence.

Comment: No, not in general. There’s no obvious normal form such expressions can be reduced to that can then be compared for structural equality. At least not in the context of SMT solving.

Comment: Yes In general it is not possible. But for subset of possible expressions itf its work then there is no need to call SMT solver each time and I can save some time also. May I know how to store array expression into memory.

Comment: I don't believe you can do that using the SMTLib format. If you use Z3 from its API via C/C++ or some other language, it might allow you to run tactics on such expressions and internally get a hold on to them; though of course that would be rather fragile since your program would depend on Z3's internal representation; assuming this is possible in the first place.